# ImageIO.read returns null

Tags: image, kotlin

I am currently developing an application called ImageResizer, and I've encountered a situation where `ImageIO.read(org.inputStream)` returns null for some unknown images. I'm wondering if there could be any errors in my code that might be causing this issue. Unfortunately, it is not easy to obtain the original images from the client. Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated!

```kotlin
fun resize(image: MultipartFile): ByteArray? {
        if (image.bytes.isEmpty()) return null

        val format = image.originalFilename!!.substringAfterLast(".")
        val inputImage = rotate(image)

        if (inputImage.width <= TARGET_WIDTH) {
            return image.bytes
        }

        val targetHeight = (TARGET_WIDTH / inputImage.ratio).toInt()
        val asBufferedImage = Thumbnails
            .of(inputImage)
            .size(TARGET_WIDTH, targetHeight)
            .asBufferedImage()

        return toByteArray(asBufferedImage, format)
    }

    private val BufferedImage.ratio: Double
        get() = 1.0 * this.width / this.height

    private fun toByteArray(outputImage: BufferedImage, format: String): ByteArray {
        val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        val isResizable = ImageIO.write(outputImage, format, outputStream)
        if (!isResizable) {
            throw IllegalStateException("cannot resize image to $format format.")
        }
        return outputStream.toByteArray()
    }

    private fun rotate(org: MultipartFile): BufferedImage {
        val orientation = runCatching {
            ImageMetadataReader
                .readMetadata(org.inputStream)
                .getFirstDirectoryOfType(ExifIFD0Directory::class.java).getInt(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_ORIENTATION)
        }.getOrDefault(1)

        val degree = when (orientation) {
            5, 6 -> 90.0
            3, 4 -> 180.0
            7, 8 -> 270.0
            else -> 0.0
        }

        val orgImage = ImageIO.read(org.inputStream)

        return BufferedImage(orgImage.width, orgImage.height, orgImage.type).apply {
            val graphics = createGraphics() as Graphics2D
            graphics.rotate(Math.toRadians(degree), orgImage.width / 2.0, orgImage.height / 2.0)
            graphics.drawImage(orgImage, null, 0, 0)
        }
    }
```

What I've tried so far is re-uploading multiple images randomly, which, as expected, did not reproduce the error.

Comment: fun? that's a keyword?

Comment: @GrindingForReputation: It is in Kotlin. I have updated the question tag so that it better reflects the language of use.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks, that should have been a keyword, idk kotlin

Comment: @GrindingForReputation for what it is worth, I usually approve of fun

Comment: Not sure what else we can say except to point out [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)) states: "_If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to read the resulting stream, null is returned_".

Comment: There should be no mystery - if you find it hard to re-produce then for debugging purposes you can `Files.copy` the image inputstream to a temp file and read it back in place of the direct read. This should give you a clue as to what type of files you are receiving that aren't in a format that ImageIO can handle